# Como usar um Break em Python?

Tags: python

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade sobre conversão, tenho esse código abaixo e queria usar um break nele para quando o usuário digitar um numero q não seja o '1' ou '0' ele de uma msg e retorne para que o usuário digite certo, mais nao to conseguindo, tem como me ajudarem ?

```py
vet = []
soma = 0
potencia = 3
for i in range(4):
     ver = int(input('Digite UM numero entre 0 e 1: '))
     if ver => 2:
          print('Digite corretamente')
          break
     else:
         vet.append(ver)
         soma = soma + (vet[i] * (2 ** potencia))
         potencia = potencia - 1
print('Codigo binario convertido em decimal é: ', binDec())
```

Comment: qual é o erro? aparentemente o código está ok

Comment: quando ele passa para o Else, ele fica num loop infinito, ao invés de chamar o input so 4 vezes como pedido !

Comment: Existem erros de sintaxe no seu código que impedem de testar o problema que relatou: `if ver => 2`, o operador `=>` não existe em Python (talvez queria usar `>=`) e a função `binDec` utilizada na última linha não está definida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar `continue` no lugar do `break`.

```
vet = []
soma = 0
potencia = 3
for i in range(4):
 ver = int(input('Digite UM numero entre 0 e 1: '))
 if ver >= 2:
      print('Digite corretamente')
      continue
 else:
     vet.append(ver)
     soma = soma + (vet[i] * (2 ** potencia))
     potencia = potencia - 1
 print('Codigo binario convertido em decimal é: ', binDec())
```

Isso vai fazer com que o loop do for continue executando mesmo que falhar até o fim de sua execução, no caso, sua condição de `range(4)`.

Answer (score 2):

Você inverteu os sinais da condição, você digitou => quando na verdade é >=, também acho que o break não seria o correto pois ele iria parar o loop, e sim o continue que apenas interrompe o ciclo atual, e você poderia trocar esse for range por um while, dessa forma:

```
vet = []
soma = 0
potencia = 3

i = 0

while(i < 4):
  ver = int(input('Digite UM numero entre 0 e 1: '))

  if ver >= 2:
    print('Digite corretamente')
    continue
  else:
    vet.append(ver)
    soma = soma + (vet[i] * (2 ** potencia))
    potencia = potencia - 1  
  i += 1

print('Codigo binario convertido em decimal é: ', binDec())
```

Este algoritmo vai executar infinitamente até obter as quatro entradas corretamente.